# The hand overlaps the text in the "may be a duplicate" notice

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, exact-duplicates

The hand overlaps the text in the "may be a duplicate" notice.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I had noticed this yesterday on a deleted question too. +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My apologies. This will be fixed in the next production build, > rev 2013.2.7.1394.

Comment: Thanks! (Looks already fixed (in the question pictured in my question above, anyway).)